# Executing UMAT subroutine in .f90 form through ABAQUS?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, subroutine, abaqus

I am using 'Abaqus standard 6.14-4' with 'Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012' and 'Intel composer XE 2013 for windows'. I have written a UMAT subroutine in free form .f90 format. Now when I try to provide this UMAT subroutine in ABAQUS, it gives me an error message, 'User subroutine file name must have a .for or .obj extension'.

I have tried to change the following lines in 'abaqus_v6.env' file:

```
compile_fortran=['ifort', '/c','/DABQ_WIN86_64', '/extend-source', '/fpp', '/iface:cref', '/recursive', '/Qauto-scalar', '/QxSSE3', '/QaxAVX', '/heap-arrays:1', # '/Od', '/Ob0', # <-- Optimization Debugging # '/Zi', # <-- Debugging '/include:%I']
```

But, may be I had made some mistake or some thing, I don't know... my problem still persist. Then, I have tried to add the following line at the top of UMAT subroutine: `!DIR$ FREEFORM` and tried to feed this to ABAQUS. But, again failed as the same error message displayed again.

Please suggest me a solution so that I can feed my .f90 subroutine to ABAQUS job.

Comment: I don't know Abaqus at all, but given it accepts object files can't use just compile your file "manually" and then provide that?

Comment: Either the freeform directive or the /free in command line would compile a .for named file with f90 format source.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. My abaqus is now accepting the UMAT file with .for extension and writing '!DIR$ FREEFORM' at the top of subroutine script. However, when I give a data check it shows me another error message 'Problem during compilation -  D:\...\XX.for'. is it because I have used modules and other features of Fortran 90, 2003 and 2008? Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: You really have to tell us the full error message end the code it relates to.

Comment: Dear Vladimir F, I have tried to put all the modules in one single .for file one by one and write the UMAT subroutine at the end. Now, ABAQUS is accepting the .for file, but when I submit the job in abaqus for analysis, it gives me the following error message: Problem during compilation - H:\ABAQUS_anlys\UMAT_Jobs\UMAT_subroutine.for'
Could you please suggest me how to handle this error?

Comment: After the problem during compilation you should see the error code and description for your particular error (in the command line).